# MySQL Update column a if not null and update column b if not null

Tags: mysql

What I would like to do is update `col_a` if `is not null` and update `col_b` if `is not null`,
For some reason I can only manage to update both columns if both are not null, I can't update one or the other if they are not null.

My attempts:

```
Update `table_A`
Set
   `col_a` = 'test a',
   `col_b` = 'test b'
Where `col_a` IS NOT NULL AND `col_b` IS NOT NULL;
```

attempt 2:

```
Update `table_A`
Set
    `col_a` = IF(`col_a` IS NOT NULL, 'test a', `col_a`),
    `col_b` = IF(`col_b` IS NOT NULL, 'test b', `col_b`);
```

How can achieve below result ?

```
+---------+---------+
| col_a   | col_b   |
+---------+---------+
|    null |  test b |
|  test a |  test b |
|  test a |    null |
|    null |    null |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Likely unrelated but single quotes should be used only for strings. Identifiers (tables/columns) should be in backticks or no encapsulation.

Comment: Look is it answer: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=0c6243089eb89cc403385a8a6c3bea7f&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev also answer needs to be IS NOT NULL, but +1 for the resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CASE expressions:

```
UPDATE table_A
SET
   col_a = CASE WHEN col_a IS NOT NULL THEN 'test a' END,
   col_b = CASE WHEN col_b IS NOT NULL THEN 'test b' END
WHERE col_a IS NOT NULL OR col_b IS NOT NULL;
```

MySql does not update a column if the new value is the same as the current value.

Answer (score 1):

- Pick all records if any column `col_a` or `col_b` is null
- Then only update each column if it is `null` otherwise not.

```
UPDATE table_A
SET col_a = IF(col_a IS NOT NULL, 'test a', col_a),
    col_b = IF(col_b IS NOT NULL, 'test b', col_b)
WHERE col_a IS NOT NULL OR col_b IS NOT NULL;
```

Example: You can verify it using a `SELECT` statement first.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    IF(col_a IS NOT NULL, 'test a', col_a),
    IF(col_b IS NOT NULL, 'test b', col_b)
FROM table_a
WHERE col_a IS NOT NULL OR col_b IS NOT NULL;
```

Check this [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q3dNfrBohNypFGto6M6zcv/3) to verify. It contains 3 output.

- **First**: Data from table.
- **Second**: `SELECT` clause to give you a glance, what records would be updated and with what values.
- **Third**: The final data in table after update.

Comment: I only want to update columns that are not null. and only update the one that is not null not both, my main problem is that if one column is null the one that is not null does not get updated

Comment: see. Let's say we picked one record where col_a is null, now `col_a` would be updated as `IF` clause in `SET` clause will be true for `col_a` only, for `col_b` it is false so would keep `col_b` as it is.

Comment: Yours also works if you make it IS NOT NULL, so basically i was missing the where clause